# generating design with java

Tags: java, png

[image]

i am trying to generate  following given sateen design with help of my java code but this code is not creating png file named sateen

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import java.io.*;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Sateen {

BufferedImage  image;
int width;
int height;
int red,green,blue; 

public Sateen() {

  try {
     File input = new File("n.png");
     image = ImageIO.read(input);
     width = image.getWidth();
     height = image.getHeight();
     //n is png file with only white pixels
     for(int i=0; i<height; i++){

        for(int j=0; j<width; j++){

           Color p = new Color(image.getRGB(j, i));
         Color g = new Color(image.getRGB(j+5, i));

                   //getting (j,i) coordinate pixel value and then comparing       it to next 5th pixel

  if(p.getRed()==255&&p.getBlue()==255&&p.getGreen()==255&&g.getRed()==255&&
    g.getBlue()==255&&g.getGreen()==255)
                   {                                  red=0;
                                      blue=0;
                             green=0; }
           //if both pixel value is white then setting 5th pixel value to black
           Color newColor = new Color(red,green,blue);


           image.setRGB(j+5,i,newColor.getRGB());
       j=j+5;

        }
     }

     File ouptut = new File("Sateen.png");
     ImageIO.write(image, "png", ouptut);
     //creating sateen png file
     } catch (Exception e) {}
   }
 static public void main(String args[]) throws Exception 
  {
  Sateen obj = new Sateen();
 }
}
```

Comment: This does not even compile. Your comments start with backslashes instead of regular slashes.

Comment: @f1sh sorry i was not fast enough with my edits - the code should be fine now

Comment: First and foremost: don't have an empty `catch` clause. If there is an exception, it swallows it and you don't know that it ever happened. Put an `e.printStackTrace()` there at the very least.

Comment: @musarrat can you provide a separate link to the n.png image with which you are working?

Comment: @MartinFrank but your edits don't fix OP's original code. What if that's the actual problem he's facing?

Comment: @f1sh thanks for that input, i merely managed to clean up the question grammatically - i had no intent/no time to review the content, sorry... (lazy me!!) it's good that you bring the things to the point!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to actually create a .png file (make sure the filepath is correct?). However this code will not generate a sateen pattern, rather draws black pixels at column 6, 12, 18 etc.

Comment: yes I think the input file is supposed to be only white image file

Comment: Indeed, at least that's what I assumed from the comment --> //n is png file with only white pixels

Also, got to get lucky not to have index out of bounds on image.setRGB

Answer (score 0):

The following code fixes some issues in your code. Although it produces an output file but the output file does not look like what you are trying to produce. Perhaps you need to tweak your algorithm?

Anyway the main thing to learn here is that if you are looping over arrays and incrementing the index within the loop then you need to take care of the situation where your index might go out of bounds of the array i.e. your `j+5` can be anything outside the image.

Also, make sure that your input file is in the correct location which will depend on where you run the program from. If you run it from the debugger/IDE then it should be inside the project folder next to the `src` folder. It would be better if you specify full path to your file i.e. `C:\SomeFolder\n.png` to avoid input file missing error.

Finally, use something like `e.printStackTrace();` in your `catch` block to find out where and why your code is failing.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import java.io.*;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Sateen {

    BufferedImage image;
    int width;
    int height;
    int red, green, blue;

    public Sateen() {
        try {

            File input = new File("n.png");
            image = ImageIO.read(input);
            width = image.getWidth();
            height = image.getHeight();
            // n is png file with only white pixels
            for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) { // may not need j++ as you are doing j+5?
                    Color p = new Color(image.getRGB(j, i));
                    int jPlus5 = j + 5;
                    if (jPlus5 < width) {
                        Color g = new Color(image.getRGB(jPlus5, i));
                        // getting (j,i) coordinate pixel value and then
                        // comparing
                        // it to next 5th pixel

                        if (p.getRed() == 255 && p.getBlue() == 255 && p.getGreen() == 255 && g.getRed() == 255 &&
                                g.getBlue() == 255 && g.getGreen() == 255)
                        {
                            red = 0;
                            blue = 0;
                            green = 0;
                        }
                        // if both pixel value is white then setting 5th pixel
                        // value
                        // to black
                        Color newColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
                        image.setRGB(jPlus5, i, newColor.getRGB());                            
                    } 
                    j = jPlus5;
                }
            }

            File ouptut = new File("Sateen.png");
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", ouptut);
            // creating sateen png file
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static public void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        Sateen obj = new Sateen();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes its working,but why u used jplus5 variable instead of passing j+5 directly in                         Color g = new Color(image.getRGB(jPlus5, i));?when i used j+5 in                for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) { // may not need j++ as you are doing j+5  ,then i am getting error ....not a statement

Comment: Using `jPlus5` variable makes it more readable, lets you store the result and also avoids duplication. I assume the error you get is because you also don't have `if (jPlus5 < width)...` in your code. If the error is because of something else then you need to let us know what error you are getting by using `e.printStackTrace();` in your `catch` block.